# Push to array checked checkbox value using each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/zYKwwYg)

So as you can see I have checkbox group, each checkbox has value.

I got the following function to find which checkbox is checked and push the value of the same checkbox to an array, like this:

> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

```
//Adding each checked checkbox to array
var left = [];
var right = [];
var all = [];
$box = $('.ppom-check-input'); //Checkbox input
$box.each(function(){ //Each checkbox
    $(this).change(function(){ //My way to figure out if got selected or not
        $('#choose').addClass('active');
        $val = $(this).val();
        $( ".all" ).click(function() {
            all.push($val);
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
            console.log(all);
        });
        $( ".left" ).click(function() {
            left.push($val);
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
        });
        $( ".right" ).click(function() {
            right.push($val);
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

Right now debugging results:

1. Checking one checkbox - array: ['1']
2. Checking two checkbox - array: ['1', '2', '2']
3. Checking three checkbox - array: ['1', '2', '2', '3',
   '3', '3']

`.right .left .all` appears each time checkbox is checked, then you will have the option to choose which array to put the checkbox value in.

I know the problem is that I'm referring to each change few times, and I need to get rid of `.change()`.

The problem is, I can't find any proper alternative to this code, I have tried replacing `.change()` function with if statements, no luck there.

How can I push multiple checked checkboxes value into array without any duplication?

Comment: Without reference to your implementation could you clearly explain what your goal is. Describe your markup, events, and goals clearly!! At the minimum give us a minimum reproducible sample.

Comment: @PeterKA I have tried to rephrase my question, take a look

Comment: Every time change fires, it binds another event....

Comment: @epascarello how can I avoid that?

Comment: You have not said much that's different. What are these elements: `.all`, `.left`, `.right` and what are the corresponding arrays for? `#choose`? The sample in Codepen does not have these elements and therefore the sample does not reproduce what you're describing here.

Comment: @PeterKA I updated the codepen, those elements are irrelevant to the question except `.all .left .right`

Comment: Thank you for putting the three classes in codepen. That does not change anything though. What do they do? What are they supposed to do?

Comment: @PeterKA Updated (under the code lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to get the values of checked checkboxes in an array is by using the `map()` and `filter()` methods as follows:

```
const checked = $box.filter(':checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
```

Every time you check/uncheck a checkbox the values in `checked` array are updated.

**NOTE**

You have not said what the following selectors refer to: `.left`, `.all`, `.right`, `#choose`. If the first three selectors are additional classes to the checkboxes then you may proceed as follows:

```
const all = $box.filter('.all:checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
const left = $box.filter('.left:checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
const right = $box.filter('.right:checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
```

The arrays too are updated each time a checkbox state changes.

If, however, these selectors refer to some other elements, you would have to make that clear in your question and code. Check out the demo below:

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $box = $('.ppom-check-input');
    $box.on('change', function() {
        const checked = $box.filter(':checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
        console.log( checked );
        const all = $box.filter('.all:checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
        const left = $box.filter('.left:checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
        const right = $box.filter('.right:checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
        console.log( all, left, right );
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input all"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input left all"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input right all"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input right"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input right all left"/>
```

If, the idea, however is to select checkboxes and then click other elements to add the checked numbers to respective arrays, the approach changes only slightly:

```
$('.all,.left,.right').on('click', function() {
    if( $(this).is('.all') ) {
        all = [...new Set( all.concat(checked) )];
    } else if( $(this).is('.left') ) {
        left = [...new Set( left.concat(checked) )];
    } else {
        right = [...new Set( right.concat(checked) )];
    }
    console.log( 'all',all, 'left', left, 'right', right );
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let checked = [], all = [], left = [], right = [];
    $box = $('.ppom-check-input');
    $box.on('change', function() {
        checked = $box.filter(':checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
        console.log( checked );
    });
    $('.all,.left,.right').on('click', function() {
        if( $(this).is('.all') ) {
            all = [...new Set( all.concat(checked) )];
        } else if( $(this).is('.left') ) {
            left = [...new Set( left.concat(checked) )];
        } else {
            right = [...new Set( right.concat(checked) )];
        }
        console.log( 'all',all, 'left', left, 'right', right );
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="chk[]" class="ppom-check-input"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="all">all</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="left">left</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="right">right</a>
```

**NOW FOR THE SOLUTION**

Here's why your code does not work as you intended.

1. **Events**

We set up event handlers, normally at DOM ready, so that when an event happens, the associated handler/function/code is executed.

```
//Example 1
$(function() {
    $('.selector1').event1(handler1);
});

//where
function handler1() {
    //some code 1
}
```

Per `example` , every time `event1` fires on `.selector1`, the function `handler1` is invoked thereby executing `some code 1`.

```
//Example 2
$(function() {
    $('.selector2').event2(handler2);
});

//where
function handler2() {
    //some code 2
    $('.selector3').event3(handler3);
}
function handler3() {
    //some code 3
}
```

Per `example 2`, whenever `event2` fires on `.selector2`, `some code 2` is executed. In addition a new event handler is set up on a new selector which in effect causes `some code 3` to be executed whenever `event3` fires. What does this mean?

If **`event2` fires three times**, followed by **`event3` once** the following will happen:

- `some code 2` will execute 3 times
- `some code 3` will execute 3 times

**This is the issue with your code.** Rarely do we set up event handlers within event handlers. So be ware of causing **a chain reaction!!**

2. **Use of `.each()`**

You do not need to use `.each()` at all; `$box = $('.ppom-check-input')` already references all elements on your page that have the class `ppom-check-input`. Therefore, `$box.change(.....)` would do just fine.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have updated my codepen, please take a look

Comment: Please take a look at the demo. Play around with it. See if it's helpful.

Comment: I have tried to implement it correctly, I get the same result

Comment: No duplicates in demo 2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loop for this:

```
$box.on('change', function(){
    $('#choose').addClass('active');
    $val = $(this).val();
    $( ".all" ).click(function() {
        all.push($val);
        $('#choose').removeClass('active');
        console.log(all);
    });
    $( ".left" ).click(function() {
        left.push($val);
        $('#choose').removeClass('active');
    });
    $( ".right" ).click(function() {
        right.push($val);
        $('#choose').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

You can call change event directly on JQuery selector.

Comment: Same result, I need to alternative to `change` because he's the trouble maker here

Comment: can you show your code on codepen or something like this?

Comment: As I said, it's part of large PHP plugin that impossible to share in codepen.
but I will try to make some mockup in codepen and share it with you when I'm finished.

Comment: You should have this code outside the loop and change event

`
$( ".all" ).click(function() {
            all.push($val);
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
            console.log(all);
        });
        $( ".left" ).click(function() {
            left.push($val);
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
        });
        $( ".right" ).click(function() {
            right.push($val);
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
        });
`

Comment: Yes but then I don't have indicator that something has changed / input has been checked.